# Hibernate session available for queries but lazyInit not working in flow

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-initialization, spring-webflow-2

I am using hibernate 4.3 and SWF 2.4 and encountered a strange behavior in a particular case which leads to a LazyInitializedException.

Here is the configuration of the flow :

```xml
<persistence-context />

<on-start>
    <!-- attach enterprise to session if not provided -->
    <evaluate expression="enterpriseInput ?: enterpriseDaoImpl.merge(externalContext.sessionMap.workingEnterprise)" result="flowScope.enterprise"/>
</on-start>

<view-state id="start" view="filiation/list">
    <transition to="showBoardOrGoToList" on="save" />
</view-state>

<action-state id="showBoardOrGoToList">
    <evaluate expression="flowController.displayBoard(event)"  />
    <transition on="yes" to="boardSubflow"/>
    <transition on="no" to="something" />
</action-state>

<subflow-state id="boardSubflow" subflow="board">
    <on-entry>
        <evaluate expression="boardFlowController.initAdmins(enterprise)" result="flowScope.admins" />
    </on-entry>
    <input name="admins" value="flowScope.admins"/>

    <output name="enterprise" value="flowScope.enterprise"/>

    <transition on="save" to="end">
        <evaluate expression="enterpriseDaoImpl.merge(enterprise)" result="flowScope.enterprise"/>
    </transition>
    <transition on="cancel" to="cancel"/>
</subflow-state>

...
```

When the flow reaches the following line :

```xml
<evaluate expression="boardFlowController.initAdmins(enterprise)" result="flowScope.admins" />
```

It will trigger a LazyInitializedException, the method initAdmins() basically does a Hibernate.initialize() on the elements of a list.

```xml
for (Administrator administrator : enterprise.getAdministrators()) {
    Hibernate.initialize(administrator);
}
```

If just before that line a method on a DAO is called it will perform the DB query without issue, **so this means that the hibernate session is available at this point** but the lazyInit is not working.

BUT, if i call initAdmins() in the `<on-start>` tag of the flow, it works...

THe flow config that works :

```xml
<persistence-context />

<on-start>
    <!-- attach enterprise to session if not provided -->
    <evaluate expression="enterpriseInput ?: enterpriseDaoImpl.merge(externalContext.sessionMap.workingEnterprise)" result="flowScope.enterprise"/>
    <evaluate expression="boardFlowController.initAdmins(enterprise)" result="flowScope.admins" />
</on-start>

<view-state id="start" view="filiation/list">
    <transition to="showBoardOrGoToList" on="save" />
</view-state>

<action-state id="showBoardOrGoToList">
    <evaluate expression="flowController.displayBoard(event)"  />
    <transition on="yes" to="boardSubflow"/>
    <transition on="no" to="something" />
</action-state>

<subflow-state id="boardSubflow" subflow="board">

    <input name="admins" value="flowScope.admins"/>

    <output name="enterprise" value="flowScope.enterprise"/>

    <transition on="save" to="end">
        <evaluate expression="enterpriseDaoImpl.merge(enterprise)" result="flowScope.enterprise"/>
    </transition>
    <transition on="cancel" to="cancel"/>
</subflow-state>

...
```

The problem is that i want to initialize the admins only when required as this is a costly operation.

There is very little information on the mechanism of the persistence-context so i couldn't find an explanation on this.

For me it really looks like a bug.

Can someone highlight me or explain why the lazyInit is broken outside of the on-start tag?
Thx

Comment: I had a similar problem. I had to change my List of items to a Set and override the equals/hashCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is causing the issue. I've experienced this before and I agree I think it is a bug as well however I don't think it's worth the effort to troubleshoot because we'd have to step into the WebFlow code (done this a few times... not fun takes hours) and I've always found a simple and unintrusive work around (5 minutes or less).

Try to initialize the admins in the following transition

```
<transition on="yes" to="boardSubflow"/>
```

see if it works now. (would be the same effect as on-start inside the subflow in terms of your goals of efficiency).

```
<transition on="yes" to="boardSubflow">
        <evaluate expression="boardFlowController.initAdmins(enterprise)" result="flowScope.admins" />
</transition>
```

If that doesn't work try to create an action-state who's sole purpose is to init admins. Place this action-state in the middle the transition -> subflow call. Make sure to evaluate the expression in either the on-start or on-exit of this action-state.

```
<action-state id="initAdminsActionState">
      <transition to="boardSubflow"/> 
      <on-exit>
          <evaluate expression="boardFlowController.initAdmins(enterprise)" result="flowScope.admins" />
      </on-exit>
</action-state>
```

Comment: i'll add it to my to do list to try to track down and report this bug but it's low priority for me :)

Comment: Thank you for answering, i have already tried to put it in the on="yes" transition as you suggested but the error also happens.
In fact, i have tried to put this initialization almost everywhere, and for example, it works in the on-entry of the "start" view-state, but outside the first view-state apparently nothing works.

I can determine if the initilalization is required at the beginning of the flow so not really an issue but this is indeed a bug.